# How do I re-use MDNavigationDrawer without re-typing the code kivymd

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I've got the below MDNavigationDrawer code but the problem is I repeat it on every screen, which is just making the code longer unessecarily. How do I write the below code once and re-use it on every screen?

```
<Example>:
    name: "example"

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "My Conversations"
                on_release: app.root.current = "conversations"
                icon: "chat-outline"
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "Personal Details"
                on_release: app.root.current = "details"
                icon: "settings"
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "Logout"
                on_release: root.clear_details()
                on_release: app.root.current = "login"
                icon: "account"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a dynamic class:

```
    <MyNavDrawer@MDNavigationDrawer>:
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            text: "My Conversations"
            on_release: app.root.current = "conversations"
            icon: "chat-outline"
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            text: "Personal Details"
            on_release: app.root.current = "details"
            icon: "settings"
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            text: "Logout"
            on_release: root.clear_details()
            on_release: app.root.current = "login"
            icon: "account"
```

Then use it as:

```
<Example>:
    name: "example"

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MyNavDrawer:
```

There may be an issue with the line `on_release: root.clear_details()`, since `root` may not end up pointing at the correct instance.

Comment: Thanks. You're right on the root.clear_details() call, I am now getting an error ```AttributeError: 'MyNavDrawer' object has no attribute 'clear_details'```. I assume I could class in my ```py``` file called MyNavDrawer and add the ```clear_details``` method to that but I would rather it be a class I already have in my py file (LoginClass). Would I just change the above from ```root.clear_details``` to something like ```LoginClass.clear_details``` (I tried this and it said LoginClass not defined).

Comment: No, you cannot use a class name there. You must use an instance reference. You can stash a reference to the instance of `Example` somewhere that the `Button` can access, or perhaps you can navigate the GUI structure of your `App` to get it.

Comment: Ok thanks, ```clear_details``` isn't a very complex method so I could just repeat it for each class in the ```py``` file. Although this does go against the very reason for me trying to condense the kv code in the first place

Comment: If you could put that method in the `App` class, then you could replace `root.clear_details()` with `app.clear_details()`.